# Angularjs and Laravel configuration in Apache2

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, apache2

I cannot make my Laravel/angularjs app to work in Ubuntu server with Apache2.

I have separated my app in frontend (Angularjs) and backend (Laravel 5).

Angularjs /var/www/app-frontend
Laravel /var/www/app-api

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName front01-app-dev
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/app-frontend


  Alias /api /var/www/app-api/public

        <Location /api>
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteRule ^ /api/index.php [L]
        </Location>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/app-api/public/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that Laravel is not being able to find the routes. A not found exception is thrown in RouteCollection. I have seen by logging some data that laravel is looking for routes defined as /api/etc (what is correct) but the request path does not includes the /api prefix.

For example one route is

Route::get('/invoices/{inovoiceId}','InvoiceController@show');

When doing a GET to http://myapp/api/invoices/101

The route is defined as api/invoices/{inovoiceId}
but the request path is invoices/101 (without the api prefix)
so the route is not found.

The final error is

```
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
in RouteCollection.php (line 184)
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 546)
```

Any idea about what is happening?

Thank you!

Sebastian

Comment: i think you ended up  with 2 `api` when you added the alias as api in the config, replace it with something else like backend

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that the api prefix is not present when laravel looks for a route.